# Consuming an external webservice from MS Dynamics CRM 2013 Online Plug-in

Tags: web-services, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have some problems consuming an external webservice from a CRM 2013 Online(sandbox) plug in, my problem is with "EnvironmentSecurity". I try to do the same with a console, and everything run fine... I  call the webservice like this:

```
NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential();
myCred.Domain = "dom";
myCred.UserName = "user";
myCred.Password = "pass";
CredentialCache credsCache = new CredentialCache();

credsCache.Add(new Uri(webAddress), "Basic", myCred);
HttpWebRequest http = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(webAddress);
http.PreAuthenticate = false;

http.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse )http.GetResponse();
```

The error is this:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
'System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, 
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

Comment: Can you please share the full URI that you are trying to call and also the Method type

Comment: Yes, is this "http://myServer.com:9999/CustomWS/Account.asmx/IsAgencia?accountid='id'" I can't show you the real url, for security sorry, :S thx!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid, you cannot make a call to local services(hosted in your local server) with a plugin registered in sandbox. Instead, please host the service with a named web address that requires DNS name resolution.

The following web access restrictions apply to this sandbox capability.

1. Only the HTTP and HTTPS protocols are allowed.
2. Access to localhost (loopback) is not permitted.
3. IP addresses cannot be used. You must use a named web address that requires DNS name resolution.
4. Anonymous authentication is supported and recommended. There is no provision for prompting the logged on user for credentials or saving those credentials.

You could host your service in Azure/ Webserver with valid Website Address.

For more information, Please visit this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx).